# Lebesgue measure of interval (p,q)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $B(\mathbb{R})$ be the Borel Sigma Algebra and $p<q$ for $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$.
We have $\mu: B(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0,\infty) \cup {{\infty}}$. For $\mu$ we have $\mu(x)=\mu(x+A)$ for a set A, also we know that the measure of the open interval $(0,1)$ is $\mu(0,1)=1$.
I want to show that for any such p and q described in the beginning:  $$\mu(p,q)=q-p$$
I tried playing around with the translation invariance but did not quite get to the result. Does anyone have a tip how to show this equation with the given information? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Probably also sigma additivity right?

Comment: All you need is that $\mu$ is a translation invariant measure on $B(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mu(U) = m(U)$ for some bounded open set $U$. I have a proof, but it uses Radon-Nikodym theorem and Fubini's theorem.

Comment: didn't have these theorems yet sadly